# Date range in presto while varchar

Tags: presto, varchar, trino

i have written the below mentioned query but the same is not getting executed, Created_at is datetime  but in varchar
error is "line 4:8: Function str_to_date not registered"

```
Select booking_id, invoice_no,hotel_id,status_name,bookings_source_name,payment_type,country_name,Created_at,hub_id,sum(bs.oyo_rooms) as brns
from aggregatedb.bookings_summary bs 
where  STR_TO_Date (bs.Created_at,'%Y-%M-%D') between STR_TO_Date('2021-03-17','%Y-%M-%D') AND STR_TO_Date('2021-03-17','%Y-%M-%D')
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

For date strings with formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, you can just cast them to the DATE type:

```
trino> SELECT CAST('2021-03-17' AS DATE);
   _col0
------------
 2021-03-17
(1 row)
```

For literals, you can [construct the DATE](https://trino.io/docs/current/language/types.html?#date) values inline:

```
trino> SELECT DATE '2021-03-17';
   _col0
------------
 2021-03-17
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you a looking for [`date_parse`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse) function with next format (based on sample data):

```
select date_parse('2021-03-17','%Y-%m-%d') as t; -- t is 2021-03-17 00:00:00.000000
```

Note that the following specifiers are not currently supported: `%D %U %u %V %w %X`